# How to change the hostname for Websphere Portal Server 6.1

Tags: hostname, websphere

I have a system with Websphere Application Server 6.1.0.35 and Websphere Portal Server 6.1.0.5. Now I changed the hostname.

Since the [official IBM note](http://www.google.de/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21390600&rct=j&q=websphere%20portal%206.1%20change%20hostname&ei=7CsxTq-rN8qr-gaX_K2eDQ&usg=AFQjCNGACTU5I6y15HUuBbTE6XoSPJe9KA&cad=rja) on this is not available anymore (400 Bad Request) - how do I tell Websphere Portal that its hostname has changed?
This has to be done especially one the default scheduled tasks, which is throwing UnknownHostException (see below).

I already did a search and replace over all .xml and .properties files in the installation directory.

```
[28.07.11 11:22:17:241 CEST] 0000008e ORBRas        E com.ibm.ws.security.orbssl.WSSSLClientSocketFactoryImpl createSSLSocket WebContainer : 1 JSSL0130E: java.io.IOException: Zeigt an, dass eine E/A-Ausnahme eingetreten ist. Ursache: oldhostname.my.domain java.net.UnknownHostException: oldhostname.my.domain
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:236)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:389)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:556)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.pc.connect(pc.java:282)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.pc.<init>(pc.java:292)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:9)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.orbssl.WSSSLClientSocketFactoryImpl.createSSLSocket(WSSSLClientSocketFactoryImpl.java:288)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSSSLTransportConnection.createSocket(WSSSLTransportConnection.java:231)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSSSLTransportConnection.createSocket(WSSSLTransportConnection.java:310)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportConnectionBase.connect(TransportConnectionBase.java:356)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport$1.run(WSTransport.java:495)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.orbimpl.transport.WSTransport.getConnection(WSTransport.java:492)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.transport.TransportBase.getConnection(TransportBase.java:187)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.TransportManager.get(TransportManager.java:93)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.getConnection(GIOPImpl.java:129)
    at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.GIOPImpl.locate(GIOPImpl.java:205)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.locate(ClientDelegate.java:1966)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate._createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1991)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1155)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1270)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1327)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1131)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1293)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1869)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1249)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(ObjectImpl.java:458)
    at com.ibm.websphere.scheduler._NotificationSinkHome_Stub.create(_NotificationSinkHome_Stub.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.NotificationSinkHolder.createBeanInstance(NotificationSinkHolder.java:273)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.NotificationSinkHolder.fireEvent(NotificationSinkHolder.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.NotificationSinkHolder.sendNotificationToListeners(NotificationSinkHolder.java:176)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.SchedulerImpl.fireNotification(SchedulerImpl.java:2538)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.SchedulerImpl$2.run(SchedulerImpl.java:976)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:241)
    at com.ibm.ws.scheduler.SchedulerImpl.cancel(SchedulerImpl.java:917)
    at com.ibm.wps.datastore.ejb.cleanup.SchedulerManagerBean.createUniqueTask(SchedulerManagerBean.java:179)
    at com.ibm.wps.datastore.ejb.cleanup.EJSRemoteStatelessSchedulerManager_03598d10.createUniqueTask(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wps.datastore.ejb.cleanup._SchedulerManager_Stub.createUniqueTask(_SchedulerManager_Stub.java:273)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.scheduler.UpdateSchedulerTaskCommand.internalExecute(UpdateSchedulerTaskCommand.java:210)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.scheduler.AbstractSchedulerTaskCommand$1.run(AbstractSchedulerTaskCommand.java:189)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:4193)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:4290)
    at com.ibm.wps.command.scheduler.AbstractSchedulerTaskCommand.execute(AbstractSchedulerTaskCommand.java:196)
    at com.ibm.wps.ai.scheduler.AITaskScheduler.registerTasksInternal(AITaskScheduler.java:210)
    at com.ibm.wps.ai.scheduler.AITaskScheduler.registerTasks(AITaskScheduler.java:114)
    at com.ibm.wps.ai.scheduler.AITaskScheduler.registerTasks(AITaskScheduler.java:84)
    at com.ibm.wps.ai.scheduler.AITaskScheduler.beginRequest(AITaskScheduler.java:379)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor91.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at com.ibm.wps.cei.ControllerImpl$Group$Handler.invoke(ControllerImpl.java:471)
    at $Proxy15.beginRequest(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
    at com.ibm.wps.services.events.ReflectHandler.invoke(ReflectHandler.java:94)
    at $Proxy16.beginRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doGet(Servlet.java:494)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:743)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.doFilter(Servlet.java:1258)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.ContentHandlerCleanup.doFilter(ContentHandlerCleanup.java:648)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.servlet.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:93)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.Servlet.service(Servlet.java:1249)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1146)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1087)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:145)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.ExtendedLocaleFilter.doFilter(ExtendedLocaleFilter.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ibm.wps.resolver.friendly.servlet.FriendlySelectionFilter.doFilter(FriendlySelectionFilter.java:191)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ibm.wps.mappingurl.impl.URLAnalyzer.doFilter(URLAnalyzer.java:381)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ibm.wps.engine.VirtualPortalFilter.doFilter(VirtualPortalFilter.java:88)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ibm.wps.state.filter.StateCleanup.doFilter(StateCleanup.java:94)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:190)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:130)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:87)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:848)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:691)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:588)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:526)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3574)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:269)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:831)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:1478)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:133)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:450)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:508)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:296)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:270)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:136)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:196)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:751)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:881)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1551)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy or quick way to change hostname in a WebSphere installation. Only thing i could think of is to find all references to the old hostname in the nice xml files and change it. Afterwards you probably need to rename quite a few files in your was/wps profile aswell.

Then pray a bit while you try starting the profile again.

To get that "error" message away just add your old hostname to etc/hosts so java can resolve it to something usefull and restart the jvm.

Comment: According to my experience, the terms "easy" or "quick" are never in the same sentence with "Websphere". However, although I can't imagine that there is no official way to do this (at least there seemed to be one documented on the IBM site), you give me a valuable workaraound with the hosts file. Thank you!
You will recieve your first checkmark if there are no better answers in, say, 1 day.

Answer (score 1):

A Google search actually found multiple useful hits for me. In summary, it appears the way to do this is with a wsadmin script:

`AdminTask.changeHostName('[-nodeName <node_name> -hostName <new_host_name>]')`

See [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/tagt_hostname.html) or [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/library/samples/SampleScripts.html).

Comment: Your URLs are for WAS 6.0, but they led me to this: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/info/exp/ae/tagt_hostname.html
Thank you!